# com.android.contacts - need apk file

Tags: contacts, apk

I want to install standard android contacts app to phone which does not have such. I could not find com.android.contacts package via google search.

Where can I get it? (or it's part of android system and there is no separate apk file in existence?)

Comment: is anyone able to answer this question?